# Can TypeScript's `readonly` fully replace Immutable.js?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, immutable.js

I have worked on a couple of projects using React.js. Some of them have used Flux, some Redux and some were just plain React apps utilizing Context.

I really like the way how Redux is using functional patterns. However, there is a strong chance that developers unintentionally mutate the state. When searching for a solution, there is basically just one answer - Immutable.js. To be honest, I hate this library. It totally changes the way you use JavaScript. Moreover, it has to be implemented throughout the whole application, otherwise you end up having weird errors when some objects are plain JS and some are Immutable structures. Or you start using `.toJS()`, which is - again - very very bad.

Recently, a colleague of mine has suggested using TypeScript. Aside from the type safety, it has one interesting feature - you can define your own data structures, which have all their fields labeled as `readonly`. Such a structure would be essentially immutable.

I am not an expert on either Immutable.js or TypeScript. However, the promise of having immutable data structures inside Redux store and without using Immutable.js seems too good to be true. Is TypeScript's `readonly` a suitable replacement for Immutable.js? Or are there any hidden issues?

Comment: Interesting question, I agree with your comments on Immutable.js, the docs are horrible and it's not the most intuitive. However, I don't think TS (read-only) would be anywhere close to being a simple swap out for Immutable.js.

Comment: what about `Object.freeze()`?

Comment: You will like this pair: Immer JS + TypeScript

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While it is true that the `readonly` modifier of TypeScript only exists at design type and does not affect runtime code, this is true of the entire type system.   That is, nothing stops you *at runtime* from assigning a number to a variable of type `string`.  So that answer is kind of a red herring... if you get warned at design time that you're trying to mutate something marked as `const` or `readonly`, then that would possibly eliminate the need for extensive runtime checking.

But there is a major reason why `readonly` is insufficient.  There is an [outstanding issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13347) with `readonly`, which is that currently (as of TS3.4), types that differ only in their `readonly` attributes are mutually assignable.  Which lets you easily bust through the protective `readonly` shell of any property and mess with the innards:

```
type Person = { name: string, age: number }
type ReadonlyPerson = Readonly<Person>;

const readonlyPerson: ReadonlyPerson = { name: "Peter Pan", age: 12 };
readonlyPerson.age = 40; // error, "I won't grow up!"

const writablePerson: Person = readonlyPerson; // no error?!?!
writablePerson.age = 40; // no error!  Get a job, Peter.

console.log(readonlyPerson.age); // 40
```

This is pretty bad for `readonly`.  Until that gets resolved, you might find yourself agreeing with a previous issue filer who had [originally named the issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13002#event-916346948) "readonly modifiers are a joke" .

Even if this does get resolved, `readonly` might not cover all use cases.  You'd also need to walk through all interfaces and types in your libraries (or even the standard libraries) and remove methods that mutate state.  So all uses of `Array` would need to be changed to `ReadonlyArray` and all uses of `Map` would need to be changed to `ReadonlyMap`, etc.  Once you did this you'd have a fairly typesafe way to represent immutability.  But it's a lot of work.

Anyway, hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: `readonly` will never cover all use cases solely because of the fact that it does not handle runtime immutability. Immutable.js is not primarily a replacement for proper type checking but an api to conveniently deal with changing objects that must be immutable. Typescript does not provide that and will never do.

Answer (score 5):

The purpose of `Immutable.js` is not to prevent a developer from doing an illegal mutation at compile time. It provides a convenient API to create copies of an object with some of its properties changed. The fact that you get type safeness on objects that you manage with immutable.js is basically just a side effect of using it.

Typescript is "just" a typing system. It does not implement any of the features `Immutable.js` does to make copies of immutable objects. All it does, when declaring a variable as `readonly`, is to check at compile time that you do not mutate it. How you design your code to handle immutability is not the scope of a typing system and you would still need a way of dealing with it.

React ensures immutability by providing a method `setState` instead of mutating the state object directly. It takes care of merging the changed properties for you. But if you e.g. use redux you may want a convenient solution to handle immutability too. That is what `Immutable.js` provides and typescript never will and it is independent of whether you like the api or not.

Comment: I know about that. However, there seems to be an implication there. If the compiler does not allow you to write code which would mutate the state, then you don't write code which would mutate the state. Thus your code-base would be "mutationless"... or, "immutated"... basically, you would achieve the goal of not mutating the state.

Comment: @Storm Well you asked if typescript can replace `immutable.js` and the answer is clearly no. Typescript ensures compile time type safety. Immutable.js ensures runtime immutability. These are two different things.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. I just cannot imagine a scenario where a runtime mutation would occur if your code-base was be "mutation-free".

Comment: @Storm But it is also not the job of immutable.js to ensure that instead of using typescript. In fact you may use both together. Immuable.js helps you dealing with modifying objects that must be immutable at runtime. If you do not use it you must still provide an own implementation to deal with that.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues with this:

1) You have to use `readonly` and/or things like `ReadonlyArray` all the way down, which is error-prone.

2) `readonly` exists solely at compile time, not runtime, unless backed by immutable data stores. Once your code is transpiled to JS your *runtime* code can do whatever it wants.

Comment: Ad 1) Is it not sufficient to have just your state model `readonly`?

Ad 2) See my comment to the answer by @trixn.

Comment: @Storm "If your codebase was 'mutation-free'" puts the onus back on the developer. Developers are error-prone. And not all mutations are as simple as `foo[1] = "hi"`, because the array index could be dynamic or wrong. TypeScript (more or less) ensures your code is correct at *compile* time: code that can't survive *runtime* due to developer, data, or user error(s) isn't all that useful. If your code is so simple that compile-time checks are sufficient, then sure, you don't need immutability at the JS level, and TS alone may be sufficient: but it doesn't handle runtime immutability.

Answer (score 1):

Immutable js distinguishing feature compared to `readonly` is [**structural sharing**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure).

Here is general benefit:
Imagine nested JS object that have 16 properties across multiple levels of nesting.

With `readonly` the way to update a value is to copy old one, modify whatever data we want and then we have new value!

With `JS` the way to update a value is to keep all the properties that did not change and only copy those that did (and their parents untill we reach a root).

Thus Immutable js saves time on update (less copying), saves memory (less copying), saves time when deciding if we need to redo some related work (e.g. we know that some leafs didn't change so their DOM do not have to be changed by React!).

As you can see `readonly` is not even in the same league as Immutable js. One is mutation property, the other is efficient immutable data structure library.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript is still rough around the edges with immutability - and they still (as of Typescript 3.7) haven't fixed the issue where you can mutate `readonly` objects by first assigning them to non-`readonly` objects.

But the usability is still pretty good because it covers almost all other use cases.

This definition which I've found in [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13923#issuecomment-557509399) works pretty well for me:

```
type ImmutablePrimitive = undefined | null | boolean | string | number | Function;

export type Immutable<T> =
  T extends ImmutablePrimitive ? T :
    T extends Array<infer U> ? ImmutableArray<U> :
      T extends Map<infer K, infer V> ? ImmutableMap<K, V> :
        T extends Set<infer M> ? ImmutableSet<M> : ImmutableObject<T>;

export type ImmutableArray<T> = ReadonlyArray<Immutable<T>>;
export type ImmutableMap<K, V> = ReadonlyMap<Immutable<K>, Immutable<V>>;
export type ImmutableSet<T> = ReadonlySet<Immutable<T>>;
export type ImmutableObject<T> = { readonly [K in keyof T]: Immutable<T[K]> };
```