# Can I add to a readonly class member array in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Give the class:

```
class Foo {
    public readonly arr: number[]
    constructor(arr: number[]) {
        this.arr = arr
    }
}
```

Given that `arr` is readonly, the following shouldn't work:

```
foo.arr = [1,2]
```

However, can I push/pop to this `arr` with:

```
const foo = new Foo([1,2,3])
foo.arr.pop()
foo.arr.push(4)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can TypeScript's `readonly` fully replace Immutable.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55905801/can-typescripts-readonly-fully-replace-immutable-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add/remove elements to a `readonly` array with no issue. The `readonly` keyword will check for reassignment and flag a compiler error if it's detected.