# readonly modifier doesn't propagate when extending classes? (TypeScript)

Tags: typescript, immutability, readonly

I'm trying to create read-only interfaces in TS, and here is an example I've tried with the `readonly` modifier propagating into subtypes:

```
type JsonDatum =
  | string
  | boolean
  | number
  | readonly Json[]
  | Object
  | null
  | undefined;

interface JsonInterface {
  readonly [key: string]: Json;
}

type Json = JsonDatum | JsonInterface;

interface Player extends JsonInterface {
  name: string;
  countryCodes: number[];
  elo: number;
}

const player: Player = {
  name: "John Doe",
  countryCodes: [1, 2, 3],
  elo: 2000
}

player.name = "123"      // No problem
player.countryCodes = [] // No problem
```

I thought that, by adding the `readonly` modifier to `JsonInterface`, interfaces extending it would also have its properties `readonly`. But there was no problem.

In order to make it work, I had to take this very non-DRY approach and manually add `readonly`s to to all of the subtype's properties:

```
...

interface Player extends JsonInterface {
  readonly name: string;
  readonly countryCodes: number[];
  readonly elo: number;
}

...

player.name = "123"      // Cannot assign to 'name' because it is a read-only property.(2540)
player.countryCodes = [] // Cannot assign to 'name' because it is a read-only property.(2540)
```

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAUgzgewHYBECGwCuBbKBeAKCigB8o5gAnASyQHMjSoAjBBAGwjSUbKR2YRKvKJS4ATZOxBQA2gF0RAeWYArCAGNgI-u3YjMScRABmtCOIDcBArWBCTaDdHjIAkknuVHzqAG9GMTRJJGk5AGsIEAAucipaOnlY1yRrAF8bUEhYRCR8HOR0LFwyFI8vHwhrW08HJ2gAZSFqNHZqAC8LAAV2NBAhKAgAD3sjOAKkcrrfAOIgkLCkNGwIWIoaems5iSkZDQRDKhAAYQRjOFj+bEFKBS3RHdCZCHYES4EhdJt9pAooMF6-UosSaNFaHW6gIGeH8jGISxWsQARDAEAALPIoBAQJEAGjhUH2h0oJzOEAucgAjLioAAmGkAZnk+OIxBebzpAAZuQQMgQfohOAA6V50AAUAL6QgAlDZJUChQjoDCkZTaQykQR5UIhUTPCTTud8gpvshBRARQhxdrKNKgA) is the code on TypeScript's playground.

I think I'm gonna switch my approach into the `Readonly<T>` generic because it seems to be the more recommended path, but [even then there seem to be problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55906256/4756173).

(The definition of `Readonly<T>` seems to close to what I'm doing though: `type Readonly<T> = { readonly [P in keyof T]: T[P]; }`. And I did try to adapt the above example with `Readonly<T>`, but unsuccesfully.)

Is this expected behavior? Is there a workaround without `Readonly<T>`?

Comment: Yes this is expected behavior, as you can see [here](https://tsplay.dev/WP94Jw), you can think of `Person` as "overriding" `JsonInterface`. The properties that aren't overridden (`[key: string]` in this case) still retain `readonly`. No there is not an easy workaround without `Readonly<T>` (which should be the utility you should be using anyways).

Comment: Cool. Then that's an answer I guess. Create one with it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior, as you can see [here](https://tsplay.dev/WP94Jw), `Person` can be thought of as "overriding" the definition in `JsonInterface`.
The effect is more observable in this [modified example](https://tsplay.dev/NBROxN).

Here it is easy to see that even though `JsonInterface` defined `readonly name`, the `Person` interface overrode it.

A helpful excerpt from the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#extending-types):

> The `extends` keyword on an interface allows us to effectively copy members from other named types, and add whatever new members we want. This can be useful for cutting down the amount of type declaration boilerplate we have to write, and for signaling intent that several different declarations of the same property might be related.

There's really no easy "workaround" for this, but you should be using `Readonly<T>` anyways (that's what it's made for!). To "make it work" with `Readonly`, you could try:

```
type Player = Readonly<{
    name: string;
    countryCodes: number[];
    elo: number;
}>;
```

which you can see [here](https://tsplay.dev/mbnM9m), results in the desired type.